# when pdo connection failed the cookie will still show the error even after fix

Tags: php, cookies

we run a php game that is based on many db's
we connect the customer on db based on which server he gets from the cookie['server']

the issue , if for any reason the pdo connection failed , the customer will still see the error and wont be able to access the website at all till the cookie time is done or he deletes the cookie ..

meaning even if we store the connection , he wont be able to login into the website unless he deletes the cookie
how can we fix this ? ..

i tried putting this in boot.php

```
          if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
  $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
  foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
      $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
     $name = trim($parts[0]);
     setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
      setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
  }
```

}

but that as you can see , will forbid any connection with every refresh..
whats the proper way of doing this. ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store DB server name to the customer's session, but not to the cookie.   Whenever the connection fails, you should change DB server name to the active DB in the customer's session on the exception.

Comment: thanks for you kind reply .., the error is "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in" , how can i distroey the session when it fails without causing issues to other users  ?